# {x:Null} vs. Transparent?

Tags: wpf, xaml

What's the difference between the following two?

```
Background="{x:Null}"
```

and

```
Background="Transparent"
```

Comment: Its exactly like setting a string `null` vs `string.Empty`. `null` will not initialize it. `String.Empty` will initialize it but put nothing. Same for Brushes. `x:null` means `null` and `Transparent` means initialized with no color and of course as other pointed out click functionality.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`Transparent` will create a brush that is initialized to a transparent color, null will set the property to null, this means that the destination property has not an brush attached. 
In WPF it's often important to set a brush to an element. If you for example want to track mouse downs in an element, you must set a background. If you don't want to set a solid color (make it opaque), you can use a transparent brush. This can be done with the string value "Transparent".
The difference lies in the manner, how the property will be set. If you assign null for a brush-property, the property will be set really to null. If you set the string "Transparent", the default [value-converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushconverter.aspx) that converts string to brushes converts this to the `Brushes.Transparent` brush.

**Short version**: `{x:Null}` sets the destination property to null. "Transparent" sets the destination property to a transparent brush.

Comment: Having a transparent background can also cause the control to be opaque to click/other events.  i.e. you may be able to see another control through the transparent background, but click events won't make it through.  This is in contrast to a null background, which would let the events through to the underlying control.

Comment: @Kent +1 didn't know that. What is with values in between 000000 and FFFFFF?

Answer (score 23):

Both are setting the *local value* of the `Background` property. The former sets it to `null` and the latter sets it to `Brushes.Transparent`.

There are a couple of important points to be aware of:

- Setting the value to `null` is *not* the same as not setting it at all. Since dependency properties obtain their effective value [from multiple sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing), setting a local value (even if it's `null`) can take precedence over values potentially sourced from elsewhere, such as a style or animation.
- Another option for controlling hit test visibility is the [`IsHitTestVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) property. This property allows you to control hit test visibility regardless of the brush with which the `UIElement` is rendered.

Comment: Interesting note on `#00000000`. What about values between black and white. Will `#00AAAAAA` be hit test visible. And also what's the point in such difference, I do see it making any sense.

Comment: From what I can tell, `#00000000` is hit test visible while null isn't. If you place a `Border` over a `Button` and set the `Border` `Background` to `#00000000`, the `Button` isn't clickable. But with `{x:Null}` it is clickable.

Comment: @Meleak: indeed, I just did some tests and found that to be the case, too. I thought maybe it was a behavioral change from earlier WPF releases, but I checked that too. Seems I was misguided - have updated my answer.

Answer (score 11):

`{x:Null}` will not be clickable, `Transparent` will.

[Also see this.](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/background-brush-help-33857292.html)

Answer (score 5):

Elements with `Transparent` background receive mouse click events when clicking on background, elements with `Null` do not.

Answer (score 1):

### The **`Transparent`** brush

Will cause the background's alpha channel to be set to **`0`** which is 100% transparent

### The **`{x:Null}`** value

Will cause the background to be set to the **default control colour by WPF** which is usually *White* on some properties like `DataGrid.RowBackground` and *Transparent* on most of the other properties.

> *It's a good habit to specify a brush colour since setting a brush to
>   **`Null`** may result in undesired default colours.*