# Is there a way to trap the MouseLeftButtonDown event on a transparent background in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I build a WPF UserControl.  This control has a transparent background.  I want to trap the MouseLeftButtonDown event, even when this event happens on the transparent background.  If I change the background to "White", or another color, the event is trapped as expected.

Is there a way to tell the control to listen for the event, even if it happens over a transparent area?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference in specifying no Background and specifying a transparent background:
[{x:Null} vs. Transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344699/xnull-vs-transparent)

Comment: You're right.  I was not specifying a background.  When I specified Background="Transparent", it worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. If this is the answer please mark it as the answer so others can benefit. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I had clicked "Answer", but I guess it didn't get through.