# A problem with using triggers in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

At the code below, when a mouse is over the grid, the grid's `Background` is expected to be red, but it isn't executed as expected.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

However, if I added the `Setter` to make the `Background` green, it would be executed properly.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/><!-- at the former, added code-->
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

I don't know why it is, but guess that there is a precedence for setting the `Background`, causing the issue. Here is [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) from MSDN, and I understand the precedence of of that reference, but I cannot link this issue to the precedence(MSDN).

Additionally, at above the code snippets, if the `Grid` is replaced with a `Button`, both these code will not be executed as expected.

---

**UPDATED: Adding Button case about this issue**

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style >
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Transparent"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your Grid has a null background, so it is not visible for mouse hit testing. If you set the Background to Transparent, then it will be hit-testable like when you set it to green.

More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344699/xnull-vs-transparent).

I tried your Button and the Background is initialized to Transparent properly. The Red value is only shown for a fraction of a second. This is because in the Aero theme (I'm on Windows 7) the Button's ControlTemplate uses a custom chrome to provide animated state transitions (i.e. when hovering etc). This custom chrome element uses internal brushes and it ignores the Background property.

This has nothing to do with property precedence. For the Grid, it's simply a matter of your Grid not being hit-testable. So it's IsMouseOver will not be set to true, unless it has a non-null background (or a child which renders something).

You can see the Precedence in action here:

```
<Grid Background="Blue">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
             <Style.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                  </Trigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

In the above, the Grid will always be Blue as that has the highest precedence (i.e. local or #3). While Red (#6) takes precedence over Green (#8).

In the case of the Button, you have something like this:

```
<Button Background="Blue">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
             <Setter Property="Template">
                 <Setter.Value>
                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                         <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                             <ContentPresenter />
                         </Border >
                         <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                             <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                 <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                             </Trigger>
                         </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     </ControlTemplate>
                 </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

In this case, there are two Background properties in play: the Button and the Border in the control template. The Button's Background property is used by the Border by default, but when the mouse is hovering it uses a Red brush. At that point, it doesn't matter what the value of the Button's Background property is set to.

Comment: If you have extra time, please read http://wangmo.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/pitfall-with-using-triggers-in-style-and-controltemplate/. Sorry for annoying. He/she mentioned this problem is that "the property on the FrameworkElement overwrites the setters in Style or ControlTemplate, Therefore, any change caused by setters will not actually bring any change." I cannot determine which is correct. To be clear, what do you think about Button case? I'll update my question soon about this.

Comment: @jwJung - Yes, if you explicitly set a property on an element like `<Grid Background="Red"` then you cannot override that with a Style. You could however change an element in your ControlTemplate, but that's no applicable to Grid. I'd have to see how you apply the Style to the Button, but in the various default themes they change the Background of an inner Border, not the Button itself, on hover/press/etc.

Comment: I'm getting better to solve this issue through your efforts. Do you let me assure this? In the precedence from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx), "if you explicitly...but that's no applicable to Grid." means the precedence 3(local value), so changing the color is no applicable due to the precedence. For Button case, my quetion's code snippet is the precedence 6(Style triggers), but since TemplatedParent template(the precedence 4) defines the Button's color(default color:gray?), the Button's Background will not be changed to the Red even if a mouse is over it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts and the answer.