# resource dictionary null brush

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary, brush

I am trying to have to "skin" resource dictionaries for a wpf application that I would like to be able to switch between. I want to be able to set the background property of several user controls to a key that is a solidcolorbrush in one dictionary and null in the other.

How do I make a resource value that is null? The following doesn't seem to work.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ticketBodyBG">{x:Null}</SolidColorBrush>
```

Is there a way to do this, or should I just use a transparent brush key?

Comment: Is there any problem with using <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ticketBodyBG" Color="Transparent"/>?

Comment: No, I just wanted to know if setting it to null was a possibility. Since transparent black is roughly equivalent, its not a big deal. I just wanted to know.

Comment: I see, but I think you need to catch the difference between null and transparent, which you may or may not know. Please refere to [{x:Null} vs. Transparent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344699/xnull-vs-transparent)

Comment: That is actually what caused me to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set to null value, simply left the `Brush` empty, it will automatically will set to `Transparent` like this -

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ticketBodyBG"></SolidColorBrush>
```

Comment: Default value will be empty if no color value is provided to Brush.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ticketBodyBG" Color="#00000000"/>
```

It is equivalent to a null background (but is different from transparent i.e: the `UIElement` will not respond to hit testing)

Comment: Throws an exception: {"'' is not a valid value for property 'Color'."}

Comment: This is still a transparent brush.

Comment: No, transparent brush is #00ffffff. WPF treats it differently

Comment: Those are both transparent. #00000000 is transparent black, #00ffffff is transparent white. I know they are treated differenly, but they are still transparent brushes.