# how to select using a wrap panel as the item panel for listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wrappanel

I want to show a list of items horizontally and be able to select from this list of items - I have tried using a listview and changing the item template per some posts on stack and I have this:

```
<ListView Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,0,0,0" Name="MachinesListView" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1455" Background="#FFF0F0F0" ItemsSource="{Binding Machines}" BorderBrush="#FFF0F0F0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" SelectionChanged="MachinesListView_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                    ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                    MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                    ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="175"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="275"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,0,0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Machine.MachineId}" TextAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Foreground="#FF639A70" FontSize="19"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Machine.Name}" TextAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="15" />
                                            <Image Source="/URM;component/Images/slot_machine-512.png" Height="60" Width="60" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Machine.Description}" TextAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="15" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0"/>
                                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="15" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0">
                                                <Run Text ="Actual: "/>
                                                <Run Text ="{Binding Actual, StringFormat=' {0:c}'}"/>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="15" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0">
                                                <Run Text ="OverShort: "/>
                                                <Run Text ="{Binding OverShort, StringFormat=' {0:c}'}"/>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>
```

This works well...I get the overall look and feel that I want from this but only selecting the first item causes the selectionchanged event to fire...

I thought about implementing the items as buttons instead but I thought there might be a more proper way of dealing with this.

Comment: What's the problem? You can't select any items from the List? It only selects the first available item?

Comment: I am only able to select the first item. Or I should say the selectionchanged event only fires when you select the first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `Background` to `Transparent` on outer most border of ControlTemplate.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Gray" Background="Transparent"
        BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10">
```

By default it's `{x:Null}` which is not responsive to mouse events.

> You will see that item gets selected only in case you click over image
>   or any control present in template but when you click on empty area
>   within border, selectionChange event doesn't fire since it is
>   unresponsive to mouse events (specifically MouseClick in your case). **Setting background to Transparent will make it responsive to all mouse events**.

Refer to this for more details - [{x:Null} Vs. Transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344737/632337).

Comment: ah - this is something to add - when using the SelectionChanged event that the selected item of the ListView never changes - however the SelectionChangedEventArgs has the data selected items datacontext in its AddedItem array.