# WPF MouseDown event not firing everywhere in a control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, mouseevent

I am currently fighting against another WPF struggle, namely mouse events.

I basically have a very simple control (a `Border` containing a `Grid` which itself has a few `TextBlocks`). I am trying to achieve a simple behavior: Double click should turn the control into edit mode (which in fact hides the `TextBlocks` with `TextBoxes` bound to the same data.

Nothing fancy, right? Well still, I'm struggling. The `MouseDoubleClick` linked to my `UserControl` just fires when I click in a control (like, clicking ON a `TextBlock`). If I click on an empty space between `TextBlocks`, nothing is fired. Not even `MouseDown`.

How could I make it work so as to catch every mouse click? I assumed that linking a `MouseDown` event to a `Border` should catch every click on the border but... it ended up not catching clicks on empty parts of the border.

Here is some draft code I made for you to run it:

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Border Height="400" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"
        MouseDown="Border_MouseDown" MouseUp="Border_mouseUp">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="BLUFF" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="BLUFF" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="BLUFF" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="BLUFF" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="BLUFF" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="BLUFF" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="BLUFF" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="BLUFF" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="BLUFF" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>

    </Border>

    <TextBlock Height="100" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" x:Name="thetext" Visibility="Collapsed"
               Foreground="White" Background="Red" Text="CLICKED!" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Border_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    thetext.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void Border_mouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    thetext.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Now try to click one of the "BLUFF" texts: A "CLICKED" Text will appear. Try clicking somewhere else, between the TextBlocks: Nothing happens.

Thank you!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
<StackPanel Background="Transparent" ... >
```

or

```
<Border Background="Transparent" ... >
```

should do the trick...

This makes the grid transparent, however visible for mouse-clicks.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344699/xnull-vs-transparent) form more Information.

There are some other circumstances, where you have to use the `PreviewXXX`- event, this is when a child element "swallows" the event away, but in your case, the above should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Well. That was unexpectedly easy - and stupid. Thanks for the quick answer.
I've always thought default background color was Transparent. Thanks a lot! There goes one day of WPF fighting