# MouseBinding Command is not fired

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, command

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding MouseDblClick}" />
    </Grid.InputBindings>
</Grid>
```

and my code-behind:

```
private RelayCommand _MouseDoubleClick;

public ICommand MouseDblClick
{
    get
    {
        if (_MouseDoubleClick == null)
        {
            _MouseDoubleClick = new RelayCommand(param => Clicked());
        }

        return _MouseDoubleClick;
    }
}

private void Clicked()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Works");
}
```

I want the messageBox to show after I double click the grid. But nothing happens. Where's the mistake?

Comment: Your code works when you click on the Grid itself (empty area). But other controls handle mouse events themselves so I guess that's the reason of your propblem.

Comment: No, grid is the only control. So there is only "empty area".

Comment: Then check the actual size of the grid, maybe it's smaller than you think and you don't actually click on it. I copied your code and it works for me.

Comment: It covers the whole window.

Comment: Set some background for it (at least transparent), then it should start to catch mouse events.

Comment: It's red now, nothing happens.

Comment: @Michal_Drwal Set the Background of `Grid` to some color.  It should work

Comment: No, it's red, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you set the `DataContext` for the `Window`

Comment: That was it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [icebat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021555/icebat) mentioned in his comments.  Try to set BG of `Grid` with some `Brush`

```
<Grid Background="Green">
    <Grid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding MouseDblClick}" />            
    </Grid.InputBindings>
</Grid>
```

By default, `Grid` will have `Background="{x:Null}"` which is not clickable as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344699/xnull-vs-transparent)

Also, Make sure that you have passed the VM object to `DataContext` of the `View`

Something like this `this.DataContext = new ViewModel();`

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTION OF ANOTHER SOLUTION:

I'm not a fan of Commands, I have another solution based on Trigger Events if it can help you:

1) Add a reference to the System.Windows.Interactivity and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions DLLs (found it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries)

2) Add this to your XAML file:

```
 xmlns:l="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
 xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```

3) Add this inside your Grid:

```
<Grid...>
     <l:Interaction.Triggers>
          <l:EventTrigger EventName="DoubleClick">
                 <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}"
                          MethodName="Clicked" />
          </l:EventTrigger>
     </l:Interaction.Triggers>
...
</Grid>
```

4) Make your Method "Clicked()" Public

I hope this will help you.