# DataTrigger RelativeSource WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

The thing I want to make When mouseover in grid Border *Visibilty* property value must change.

I have a grid with a 3 ColumnDefinition.

[image]

The code is

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="27*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="93*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Blue" Visibility="Hidden">
           <Border.Style>
                <Style>
                   <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver , RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
                   </Style>
               </Border.Style>
          </Border>
        <Image  Grid.Column="1" />
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" />

   </Grid>
```

When mouseover the grid nothing is happen.so This codes not working

Comment: Your DataTrigger use `IsReadOnly` as property. So what do you expect?

Comment: If the default `Grid` has `IsReadOnly` property, you must be using a future .NET framework.

Comment: @Clemens Sorry I didnt see it(I have copied this solution)Now I changed to IsMouseOver but not working agaion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one thing is that you should not use `IsReadOnly` property in DataTrigger when MouseOver is required.

another one is that local value `Visibility="Hidden"` has higher priority than DataTrigger setter `<Setter Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Visible" />` and will not be changed even if condition is true

a fix for both (initial value of `Visibility` is defined in a setter)

```
<Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Blue">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

you should also set Grid Background to non-null value (e.g. `<Grid x:Name="grid1" Background="Transparent">`) for mouse movements to be registered in grid ([{x:Null} vs. Transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344699/xnull-vs-transparent))

Comment: When I change binding to IsPressed or IsFocused in grid again.This is not working.

Comment: `Grid.IsFocused = false` and doesn't change, that's why Border is visible. it is working but not how you expected. Grid doesn't have `IsPressed` property, how do you use it?