# WPF Button highlights only over text

Tags: wpf, xaml

The button highlights only when my mouse is over the text, I want it to highlight when my mouse is over the button.

```
<Button Content="Characters" Click="BtnClickP1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="124" Height="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF282A30"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF282A30"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

Comment: don't set {x:Null} Background. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344699/xnull-vs-transparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the Background Transparent.

Comment: no, they don't have to set the Background Transparent. it can be any brush, not just SolidColorBrush

Comment: when i do this nothing highlights at all

edit nvm i got it

Comment: I have just tried it with this code, it seems to work

`<Button Content="Characters" ... >
      <Button.Style>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/> etc.`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is already working, however a null background affects the MouseOver event.

```
<Button Content="Characters" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="124" Height="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/> <!-- Here to Transparent -->
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF282A30"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF282A30"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```